# putting an image on top of another with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im using 2 images for my blog, the main image and an image when the user rolls over, right now the second image replaces the first, is it possible to have the second image hover over the first on hover?

this is the code i have:

```
<a href="blog-inner.html" title="blog title"><img src="images/blogpost2.jpg" alt="blog post title" class="img-responsive imghover"></a>
```

jquery:

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function(){
           var blog1 = '';

              $(".imghover").hover(function() {
                   //save previous image in variable
                   blog1  = $(this).attr('src');
                   $(this).attr("src","images/imghover.png").animate(800);
                 }, function() {
                      $(this).attr("src",blog1);
              });


         });

        </script>
```

Comment: You want to show the second image when user hover the first image right ?

Comment: It would be simpler to place a background image on the `a` element and use the CSS `:hover` property to amend it, no JS required.

Comment: zera tops yes that is correct. rory could this be used if i have no idea what images the user is going to be uploaded?

Comment: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/  this might be what you're looking for.